# Why didn't Eddie Willers ever connect some of the disappearances to his conversations with the Mystery Worker?

Tags: character-analysis, atlas-shrugged, ayn-rand

Eddie Willers periodically ate dinner in the Taggart cafeteria with the Mystery Worker (who is, of course, later identified as John Galt). They discuss a lot of different things, including the state of the world and Taggart Transcontinental.

With that said, given the fact that much of the concrete information Eddie supplies to the Mystery Worker is promptly used by the Strikers to the detriment of Taggart Transcontinental, why didn't Eddie ever put two and two together (especially given how obviously pointed a few of the Mystery Worker's questions were)?

For example, Eddie Willers mentioned that Dick McNamara was going to be the contractor on the John Galt Line to the Mystery Worker, and he disappeared shortly after that.

He mentions their great need of diesel engines and who they'll be ordering them from. The Mystery Worker pointedly asked about how critical the diesels were, and the would-be manufacturer promptly disappears.

Same thing for Quentin Daniels (although admittedly the disappearance of Daniels was kind of overshadowed by the simultaneous disappearance of Dagny herself, along with the fact that Quentin Daniels was working for Dagny directly rather than through Taggart Transcontinental).

There were a number of other strange occurrences with information that Eddie shared with the Mystery Worker. So why didn't Eddie ever figure out who he was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When John Galt gave his radio address, Eddie immediately recognized him as the Mystery Worker. He quickly connected him to all of the disappearances, including the fact that he was actively destroying Taggart Transcontinental. He also noticed, significantly, that the last day he saw John Galt was the night that Dagny left for Utah (when both of them went after Quentin Daniels and Dagny followed John to the Gulch). He even inferred the nature of the relationship between him and Dagny.

Talking to Dagney, he said,

> "Ive talked to him... I've been talking to him for years... in the Terminal cafeteria... He used to ask questions... all sorts of questions about the railroad, and I - God, Dagny! was I protecting the railroad or was I helping to destroy it?"
>   "Both. Neither. It doesn't matter now."
>   "I could have staked my life that he loved the railroad!"
>   "He does."
>   "But he destroyed it."
>   "Yes."
>   "I used to talk to him," he said, after a while. "His face... Dagny, it didn't look like any of the others, it... it showed that he understood so much... I was glad, whenever I saw him there, in the cafeteria... **I just talked... I don't think I knew that he was asking questions...** but he was... so many questions about the railroad... and about you."

John Galt helped him in a very visceral way. He doesn't appear to have been fully aware of the amount of information he gave John until after the fact. (He didn't even realize, for example, that he had told John Galt the location of the cabin in the woods that she went to after Directive 10-289 went into effect, which enabled Francisco D'Anconia to find her and try to persuade her to come to Galt's Gulch with him).